# How to deal with GeoJson in CKAN DataStore?

Tags: geojson, ckan

Is it true CKAN DataStore is able to deal with GeoJson? I've not seen any reference in the documentation except for this [link](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/data-viewer.html#datastore-map) about the DataStore Map visualization, saying:

> Shows data stored on the DataStore in an interactive map. It supports plotting markers from a pair of latitude / longitude fields or from a field containing a GeoJSON representation of the geometries.

Thus, I'm supossing GeoJson is accepted in DataStore columns. Anyway, I've [not found](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#valid-types) any GeoJson CKAN type, thus, again, I'm guessing the simple Json type must be use for this purpose.

Can anybody confirm this? Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I've created a resource and a datastore and a "recline_map_view" associated to the resource. Then, I've upserted a value, which is shown by this `datastore_search` operation:

```
$ curl -X POST "https://host:port/api/3/action/datastore_search" -d '{"resource_id":"14418d40-de42-4fdd-84f7-3c51244c7469"}' -H "Authorization: xxx" -k
{"help": "https://host:port/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search", "success": true, "result": {"resource_id": "14418d40-de42-4fdd-84f7-3c51244c7469", "fields": [{"type": "int4", "id": "_id"}, {"type": "text", "id": "label"}, {"type": "json", "id": "geojson"}], "records": [{"_id": 1, "geojson": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [48.856699999999996, 2.3508]}, "label": "Paris"}], "_links": {"start": "/api/3/action/datastore_search", "next": "/api/3/action/datastore_search?offset=100"}, "total": 1}}
```

Nevertheless, nothing is shown in CKAN :(

**EDIT 2**

It was a problem with my CKAN. I've tested Ifurini's solution at demo.ckan.org and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoJSON is just a (particular kind of) JSON, so it does not have a particular treatment as a database field.

So, you can create a resource with a GeoJSON field from a simple CSV file like this:

```
Name,Position
"Paris","{""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[2.3508,48.8567]}"
```

(note the *double* double quotes `""` instead of just a *single* double quote `"`)

If you call the column "GeoJSON" (or "geojson", "gEoJsOn", etc., as capitalization is not important) the Map View will automatically use that field to mark the data in the map, instead of just letting you manually select which field to use.